# Grid lines are not showing primeng table

Tags: angular, primeng

Created a table grid using  and sometimes the vertical or horizontal lines are not showing up. When I change the zoom percentage or refresh the page or scroll to different section within the same window, the lines appear again.

Referring to the CSS properties, everything is defined correct.

And this issue is not happening with all the browsers or systems.. It is random and ambiguity

`<p-table  id="sendReminderTable" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="calc(100vh - 300px)" [(selection)]="reminderSelectedRows"  [columns]="sendReminderCols" [paginator]="true" [rows]="100" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[100, 200, 500]" [value]="sendReminderData" resizableColumns="true" columnResizeMode="expand" reorderableColumns="true"  sortMode="multiple" #dt  >`

Comment: Can you please provide your code or stackblitz link ?

Comment: Are you adding the style class to the table? like this: `<p-table styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines">`

Comment: @Stoobish Adding styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines" did not help.. And this issue is inconsistent. Not happening with all users and all resolutions. Occurred random & only with few people only.

Comment: @PiyushJain Added code snippet for your reference

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this issue was that I hadn't imported a theme to get the base styles for the gridlines.

Because the colour of the gridline is a particular colour the style is in the theme file

Answer (score 0):

Prime ng has option to show or hide grid lines. To show use "p-datatable-gridlines" as style class .
Viz.

Comment: <p-table styleClass ="p-datatable-gridlines">

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).